# How To Run JApplet Class As Main Project Class

Tags: netbeans, applet, project, program-entry-point

Very simple question here: I'm using Netbeans and Im making an applet, how can I make it so that that my JApplet class runs whenever I het the big green play button (ie Run Project).

Steps that I took to create the project:
Create new Java Class Library
Add file > new JApplet File called "NewApplet"

This automatically generates the applet. It runs perfectly if you right click and select Run File. But yeah... how can I get the project or the IDE to recognize it as the main class??

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Just beacuse its easy to use as a base for a jframe app instead of coding the whole jframe

Comment: *"Just beacuse its easy to use as a base for a jframe app instead of coding the whole jframe"*  Almost anything that can done in an applet or frame is (far) easier in a frame.  But then, I don't' really understand what you mean by 'base for a jframe'.  My advice would be to develop this GUI in a `JPanel` that is displayed in a `JFrame` or a `JOptionPane`.  Only once it is working, should you try and put the `JPanel` into an applet.